Module parse failed: Unexpected token in react-idle-timer with React Scripts
I’m encountering an error when trying to compile my React project that uses the react-idle-timer package. The error points to an unexpected token in index.esm.js of react-idle-timer, specifically on line 239. Since I’m using React Scripts (not a custom Webpack configuration), I’m not sure why this error is happening. Any suggestions would be great!
React version: 17.0.2
react-idle-timer version: 5.7.2
React Scripts version: 4.0.3

